# Taking snapshots of an animation in PDE toolbox in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have solved a pde numerically in *PDE toolbox* and have can play an animation of the solution. I would like to make "snapshots" at certain time steps $t=0,\ t=0.25,\ \ldots,\ t=1$, but cannot find this functionality. Also I cannot find a way to save the animation for external use. Any advice?

Comment: (https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html)

Comment: learn how to actually do it in the language instead of using premade functions for everything. you can check up the functions "figure" "plot" "pause" "drawnow" and "help" should get you started.